# Building Android APK in Ionic and Cordova

Tags: javascript, html, css, cordova, ionic-framework

I made an app in Ionic and I am trying to build APK with: ionic cordova build --release android but it says these errors:

1. > Without `from` option PostCSS could generate wrong source map and will not find Browserslist config. Set it to CSS file path or to `undefined` to prevent this warning.
2. > ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Viktor_2\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
   >   JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\java\jdk-10.0.1
   >   (node:1380) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8 or greater

Comment: What have you done so far? Are you using the correct JDK version?

Comment: i am using jdk 10

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the JDK 10  and install jdk 1.8 and set the path  and then try to build it will work as there is a issue with JDK 10 it wont work perfectly with ionic